# Can scientists name themselves in the scientific name when they discover a new taxon?

Tags: taxonomy, species

There are sometimes people names in taxonomy, like *Myotis keenii* was names after Mr. Keen who contributed to discover the species. So, if you discover a species and someone else is constructing the scientific name and names you, it's clear. But when *you* discover a species and *you* publish it in a paper, can you propose a scientific name that contains your name? Has it ever happened, or is it considered an unhealthy practice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is that in general, self-naming is severely frowned upon in the scientific community, but the act itself is not disallowed.

There have been at least two instances of self-naming recorded in literature, as stated in John Wright's book [*The Naming of the Shrew*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yphEBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA295&ots=vDsDAzjbI1&dq=taxonomy%20%22self%20naming%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 34, where [Jules Bourguignat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Ren%C3%A9_Bourguignat) named a species of snail after himself as *Ferussacia bourguignatiana*. The naming was apparently very poorly received (being referred to as taxonomic [onanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation)), although I was unable to confirm this by locating the original citation.

Another example was given in the book on [Sigismund Hochenwarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund_Ernst_Hohenwart) who named a species of moth (now [*Syngrapha hochenwarthi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syngrapha_hochenwarthi)) after himself (original citation [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/25003342.pdf?acceptTC=true)).

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, effectively, no?

Comment: @SiyuanRen Pretty much, you can if you want, but it will lead to you being ridiculed by the community.

Comment: @Tomas Isn't this answer enough for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: "*Taxonomic onanism*" is a great term.

Comment: As this example shows, it's not terribly uncommon to name a species after a family member. Linnaeus, for example, named the plant genus *Linnaea* after his wife.